# Mysql update multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, many-to-many

I have 2 tables. 'media_id' from category table references 'id' from media table. Each item in media table can have zero or more categories from category table.

media table

---

```
| id | options
|----------------|
| 1  | ...  
|----------------|
| 2  | ...    
|----------------|
| 3  | ...    
|________________|
```

category table

```
 __________________________
| id | category | media_id |
|--------------------------|
| 1  | fashion  | 1        |
|--------------------------|
| 2  | sport    | 2        |
|--------------------------|
| 3  | sport    | 3        | 
|--------------------------|
| 4  | cats     | 4        |
|--------------------------|
| 5  | dogs     | 4        |
|--------------------------|
| 6  | sport    | 5        | 
|__________________________|
```

When I save data in table I want to update categories. My old fashion way would be:

For each media:

1. delete previous categories:

   delete from category table where media_id = %d
2. add new categories

for each category: (there can be zero or more)

insert into category table (category, media_id)

This works well, however its running a lot of queries (for each media, delete previous categories + insert new category for each new category if categories exist on that media).

I already have a constrain in category table that references media table with that media_id, and everytime media is deleted, all categories will be deleted for that media. This works well.

The question is when someone edits all this media (add and removes some categories on all those media) and I want to save these changes.

How could I improve this process of updating category table?

Comment: this should be first normalized, and there should be a relationship table, so you can stored all categories in one table and add only new ones, the table will never be that big. The media table and the relation table are the only ones that must go so when you delete a media you remove the relationship in a trigger. When you add you add also new rows into the relation ship

Comment: Can you explain more please? I have edited my question with more info about what I want to achieve.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

You need three tables and some reprogramming

First table: `media(mid,etc,etc2)`

```
| mid| options
|----------------|
| 1  | ...  
|----------------|
| 2  | ...    
|----------------|
| 3  | ...    
|________________|
```

Second table: `category (cid,category)`

```
| cid | category |
|---------------|
| 1  | fashion  |
|---------------|
| 2  | sport    |
|---------------|
| 3  | cats     |
|---------------|
| 4  | dogs     |
|---------------|
| 5  | frogs    |
|_______________|
```

Third, a relationship table: `rel_cat_media(id , ref_cid  ,  ref_mid)`

```
| id | ref_cid  |  ref_mid |
|--------------------------|
| 1  |    1     | 1        |
|--------------------------|
| 2  |    3     | 2        |
|--------------------------|
| 3  |    2     | 3        | 
|--------------------------|
| 4  |    3     | 4        |
|--------------------------|
| 5  |    4     | 4        |
|--------------------------|
| 6  |    2     | 5        | 
|__________________________|
```

And here the create tables

```
CREATE TABLE `media` (
  `mid` BIGINT  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `etc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `etc` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `etc` varchar(20) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `cid` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `category`  varchar(20) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `rel_cat_media` (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ref_cid BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ref_mid BIGINT NOT NULL,
    INDEX (ref_cid , ref_mid),
    UniQUE (ref_cid , ref_mid)
);
```

You never delete categories only add to them, when you have new categories.

When you **delete** media You have a `AFTER DELETRE TRIGGER` that also deletes all rows the have the media_id from the delete media so you can delete more than 1 media at once and delete al related rows.

A new media row can be inserted with or without rows in the relationship table.
But that can be made by choosing the categories in the gui and then running a loop with the the new inserted mid(media id).

It is so only a little programming and you have not much trouble.

Only the `SELECT` query needs another `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Such structure requires heavy changes to my current layout, but it its a right way to do this I am willing to try.

Comment: yes this is always a problem with not normalized tables, but for mysql you can write INSERT I'NTO SELECT querys, the trigger is simple, the rest is some work.

Comment: rel_cat_media table has 2 primary keys and id column. Why do you need id column here? it does not mention id column in user_roles  table https://grokonez.com/sql/sql-tutorial-mysql-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: It is because i don't define foreign keys and keep the id as primary key autoincrement with the combine Index, in rare cases i reference also the relationship table to another table so i have only 1 bigint to reference.and to fields. besides i will not get faster. Another upside is when you delete a categorie the relationship table go to nothing, with out an error

Comment: can you edit your solution with create table syntax for each table?

Comment: Look you can take my approach and modify it, it is not set in stone, if you want the foreign keys and no id column do it., it will work exactly, also you will find other solutions as the come to light in the furtherdevelopment

Comment: how would you insert if not exist multiple rows in rel_cat_media with single query?

Comment: you must INSERT INTO rel_cat_media VALUES (NULL,1,1),(NULL,1,2),(NULL,1,3);  like i said you must have chososen all your wanted category and then you loop overy all choises and add to thelist

Comment: but how woudl this not create duplicates? if you use insert on duplicate key update you would need to know primary key.

Comment: yes without the un ique constraint, you would get doubles, if you don't check it, so i added a UNIQUE Restraint, as i told yold, improve my idea and edit my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215443/discussion-between-toniq-and-nbk).